# Vim 8 terminal not properly sourcing vimrc on startup due to t_ut (Windows)

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

I have just been setting up a colour scheme for vim (namely onedark) and following advice elsewhere on the internet ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/832)). I added the line `set t_ut=""` to my `.vimrc`. When I re-source my `.vimrc` with `:so %` it loads properly as I would expect.

However, when loading vim from the command line it appears to rapidly send various messages to the screen faster than it is possible to read. It then prompts me to `press ENTER or type command to continue`, as it normally does when encountering an error.

I know that the problem is caused by the `set t_ut=""` line since it works fine without this line (but the colourscheme doesn't properly apply), and I have moved it around the file to no avail.

I'm using Windows Terminal version 1.6.10571.0 and Vim version 8.2.

I have tried running vim with the `-V` flag but there was nothing that seemed like an issue (though I don't really know how to interpret this).

Anyone know how I can avoid having to open my `.vimrc` and source it manually every time I open vim?

[Output of `:messages`](https://pastebin.com/bY78kAfg) There is also equivalent messages for other colours but they aren't all displaying at once.

[Output after pressing `f` after starting in debug mode](https://pastebin.com/tPxHs8j0)

After bisecting my `.vimrc` it seems the error is actually the line
`colorscheme onedark`. This seems to imply it's either an issue with the colourscheme itself or the installation.
I'm using the Vim 8 plugin system (idk what it's called, the one where you put it in the file path), and in the folder

```
C:\users\[username]\vimfiles\pack\visuals\start\onedark.vim-master
```

I have folders .github, autoload, build, colors, img and term (as well as some `.md` files)

Comment: Check `:messages`, perhaps? What advice are you following (links)? It shouldn't be necessary to mess with the various `t_` settings unless (1) you're doing something fairly strange or (2) `TERM` and the terminal info database don't cooperate with vim to communicate the correct features.

Comment: *When I re-source my vimrc* This is just my opinion, but the vimrc is not meant to be re-sourced.  You can try, and with some (or a lot of) care, it might look like it works, but sooner or later you'll find out it create some subtle issues which require even more care.  There is an alternative to re-sourcing the vimrc, but it would be out of scope for this question.  As for your issue, try to start in debug mode with:  `vim -D`.  Then, run `n` to stop before the next Ex command, or `f` to stop before the next sourced script.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble It wasn't showing the background properly, so I followed the advice posted in the github of Msoft terminal (have editted to add link). `:messages` did seem to show some errors

Comment: @user938271 I agree that it is not meant to be done, but I do when I want to test that my new lines work. I've edited to add the result as you suggested

Comment: Try to [bisect your vimrc](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim_faq/blob/7f9c65c91d01e289a92b9e43a70ee2becadd66ce/vim_faq.txt#L1153-L1228).  That is reduce the amount of code it contains as much as possible, without making the issue disappear; then include the result in your original post.

Comment: @user938271 have done, looks like an installation issue so have also added details about that. (it's also the first colourscheme I've downloaded)

Comment: I wonder if there is a difference between `set t_ut=""` and `set t_ut=`